# Schwartz-Kristoffel conformal mapping

Tags: integration

I have the following function from the Schwartz-Kristoffel conformal mapping,

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\omega(\zeta) &= c\int_{}^{\zeta}\left(1-\dfrac{a_1}{t}\right)^{a_1-1}\left(1-\dfrac{a_2}{t}\right)^{a_2-1}...\left(1-\dfrac{a_k}{t}\right)^{a_k-1}dt \\ &=c\int_{}^{\zeta} \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(1-\dfrac{a_k}{t}\right) ^{\alpha_k-1} dt
\end{split}
\end{align}

It says that since $|a_n|=1$, $|t|>1$, expanding the integrand of the above equation into series and integrating, one obtain,
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\omega(\zeta)=c\left\lbrace\zeta-[(a_1-1)a_1+(a_2-1)a_2+...+(a_k-1)a_k]\ln\zeta+\dfrac{e_1}{\zeta}+\dfrac{e_2}{\zeta^2}+... \right\rbrace 
\end{split}
\end{align}

Can someone explain how do we get to that last equation above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us make some preparations at first.

*Preparation 1.* Thanks to the fact that $\left|a_k\right|=1$ and that $\left|t\right|>1$, we have $\left|a_k/t\right|<1$, for which the logarithmic function yields the following expansion
$$
\log\left(1-\frac{a_k}{t}\right)=-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m}\left(\frac{a_k}{t}\right)^m.
$$

*Preparation 2.* Note that the exponential function is holomorphic on the whole complex plane, i.e., $\forall\,z\in\mathbb{C}$,
$$
\exp z=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p!}z^p.
$$

With the above two preparations, we may rewrite the original integrand as follows.
\begin{align}
I&=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{a_k}{t}\right)^{a_k-1}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\exp\left[\left(a_k-1\right)\log\left(1-\frac{a_k}{t}\right)\right]&\text{(using $a^b=e^{b\log a}$)}\\
&=\exp\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(a_k-1\right)\log\left(1-\frac{a_k}{t}\right)\right]&\text{(using $e^{a_1}e^{a_2}\cdots=e^{a_1+a_2+\cdots}$)}\\
&=\exp\left[-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(a_k-1\right)\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m}\left(\frac{a_k}{t}\right)^m\right]&\text{(using preparation 1)}\\
&=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p!}\left[-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(a_k-1\right)\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m}\left(\frac{a_k}{t}\right)^m\right]^p.&\text{(using preparation 2)}
\end{align}
This last line implies that the integrand is no more than a power series with respect to $1/t$. That is, as one expands all brackets and parentheses therein, the result reads
$$
I=c_0+c_1\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)+c_2\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)^2+\cdots=c_0+\frac{c_1}{t}+\frac{c_2}{t^2}+\cdots,
$$
where each $c_j$ is a constant. These constants can be determined from the expression of $I$ from above. For example, $c_0$ is the constant coefficient, which corresponds to the $p=0$ term in the expression (because any $p>0$ term would include $1/t$). When $p=0$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{p!}\left[-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(a_k-1\right)\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m}\left(\frac{a_k}{t}\right)^m\right]^p=\frac{1}{0!}\left[-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(a_k-1\right)\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m}\left(\frac{a_k}{t}\right)^m\right]^0=1.
$$
Thus
$$
c_0=1.
$$
Likewise, $c_1$ corresponds to the $p=1,m=1$ term, because the least order of $t$ in any $p>1$ term is $\left(1/t\right)^p$, while the least order of $t$ in any $p=1,m>1$ term is $\left(1/t\right)^m$. Taking $p=m=1$, and we eventually have
$$
c_1=-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1-a_k\right)a_k.
$$

Now, the integration of the integrand is of the form
$$
\int^{\zeta}I{\rm d}t=\int^{\zeta}\left(c_0+\frac{c_1}{t}+\frac{c_2}{t^2}+\frac{c_3}{t^3}+\cdots\right){\rm d}t=c_0\zeta+c_1\log\zeta-\frac{c_2}{\zeta}-\frac{c_3}{2\zeta^2}+\cdots,
$$
or, by using the above values for $c_0$ and $c_1$,
$$
\int^{\zeta}I{\rm d}t=\zeta-\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1-a_k\right)a_k\right)\log\zeta+\frac{e_1}{\zeta}+\frac{e_2}{\zeta^2}+\cdots,
$$
where $e_j$'s are constants made up of $c_j$'s, e.g., $e_1=-c_2$ and $e_2=-c_3/2$.

Finally, there is a common factor $c$ in front of all terms. Taking this term into consideration, and one obtains
$$
\omega(\zeta)=c\int^{\zeta}I{\rm d}t=c\left[\zeta-\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1-a_k\right)a_k\right)\log\zeta+\frac{e_1}{\zeta}+\frac{e_2}{\zeta^2}+\cdots\right],
$$
as is expected.

Comment: Hi hypernova. Thanks for your answer! Do you mind to have a live chat discussion? I still cannot understand some of the steps above.

Comment: Do you mind to expand the derivation from step #2 to #3 and from #3 to #4 above?

Comment: Or perhaps, explain what was actually used to derive step #2 to #3 and from #3 to #4 above?

Comment: @BeeTiau: Sure! Apology for this delayed response. Can we start a live chat now? Plus, were you asking how the integrand is expanded to series or how the $c_0$ and $c_1$ are determined?

Comment: Hi hypernova, I think if you could help me to expand the derivation, that would great. I think that's better for the benefit of everyone than just to have a live chat that I previously asked for.

Comment: Yes, correct, it is still hard for me to follow the derivation. I would appreciate if you could do the derivation at a much slower pace. Your answer above is so much helpful already...

Comment: @BeeTiau: Sure. Thank you for your feedback. I am editing accordingly.

Comment: Thank for your willingness to edit and expand the derivation @hypernova

Comment: @BeeTiau: My pleasure. I just updated my answer. Would you please see if it is clearer now? Thanks :-)

Comment: Hi @hypernova, sorry for my late response. Yes, I really appreciate your effort to answer and to refine your derivation!

Comment: @BeeTiau: My pleasure :-)